# Building App Bundle Proguard Error

Tags: proguard, android-bundle, android-studio-3.2

When i try to build app bundle with android studio 3.2 canary 17 i get the following error message. i have no idea what is missing angular bracket went through all of my proguard files and everything seems fine and is working in older version of android studio. gradle build tools is com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha17 and distribution url is distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Job failed, see logs for details
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.transform(ProGuardTransform.java:194)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor915.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.execute(ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.java:66)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing closing angular bracket
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.doMinification(ProGuardTransform.java:255)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.access$000(ProGuardTransform.java:63)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform$1.run(ProGuardTransform.java:171)
at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:47)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:282)
... 1 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing closing angular bracket
at proguard.util.ClassNameParser.wildCardIndex(ClassNameParser.java:312)
at proguard.util.ClassNameParser.parse(ClassNameParser.java:211)
at proguard.util.ListParser.parseEntry(ListParser.java:101)
at proguard.util.ListParser.parse(ListParser.java:75)
at proguard.util.ListParser.parse(ListParser.java:55)
at proguard.ClassSpecificationVisitorFactory.createClassVisitor(ClassSpecificationVisitorFactory.java:549)
at proguard.ClassSpecificationVisitorFactory.addMemberVisitors(ClassSpecificationVisitorFactory.java:395)
at proguard.ClassSpecificationVisitorFactory.createClassVisitor(ClassSpecificationVisitorFactory.java:366)
at proguard.ClassSpecificationVisitorFactory.createCombinedClassVisitor(ClassSpecificationVisitorFactory.java:321)
at proguard.ClassSpecificationVisitorFactory.createClassPoolVisitor(ClassSpecificationVisitorFactory.java:161)
at proguard.KeepClassSpecificationVisitorFactory.createClassPoolVisitor(KeepClassSpecificationVisitorFactory.java:285)
at proguard.KeepClassSpecificationVisitorFactory.createClassPoolVisitor(KeepClassSpecificationVisitorFactory.java:215)
at proguard.KeepClassSpecificationVisitorFactory.createClassPoolVisitor(KeepClassSpecificationVisitorFactory.java:101)
at proguard.DescriptorKeepChecker.checkClassSpecifications(DescriptorKeepChecker.java:78)
at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:305)
at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:271)
at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:113)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.BaseProguardAction.runProguard(BaseProguardAction.java:64)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.doMinification(ProGuardTransform.java:249)
... 6 more
```

Answer (score 5):

The error is due to a proguard incompatibility of [Urban Airship](https://www.urbanairship.com/) with Gradle plugin 3.2.0 and greater, and has been fixed in Urban Airship 9.1.1 (as per the [changelog](https://github.com/urbanairship/android-library/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)). Just update your dependency to Urban Airship 9.1.1 or greater and the error will disappear:

```
implementation 'com.urbanairship.android:urbanairship-gcm:9.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably thrown by rule(s) defined in one of the dependencies of your project. In my case culprit was UrbanAirship (v9.1.0 which is deprecated); upgrading to v9.3.2 resolved the issue.